# Let p be a positive number. If $∆$ is an equilateral triangle with perimeter $P = 2s$, prove that $\text{area}(∆) = \frac{s^2}{\sqrt{27}}$

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation

Let $p$ be a positive number. If $\triangle$ is an equilateral triangle with
perimeter $P = 2s$, prove that $\text{area}(\triangle) = \frac{s^2}{\sqrt{27}}$

The definition of $\text{area}(\triangle) = \dfrac{\sqrt{3}P^2}{36}$

so given $P$ and plugging it in i get

$$\frac{\sqrt{3}\left(2s\right)^2}{36}$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{3}\cdot 4s^2}{36}$$

which i can reduce the $\frac{4}{36}$ to $\frac{1}{9}$ but i dont understand how that is getting me closer to the correct answer..

Comment: The statement that $\text{area}(\triangle) = \dfrac{\sqrt{3}P^2}{36}$ is not a _definition_; it is a derived result. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Okay, so should i not be using that formula?

Comment: There's nothing in the fact that it is proved rather than a definition that says you shouldn't be using it.

Comment: bruh literally $\frac{1}{\sqrt{27}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{9}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

I suppose that you know that if $a$ is the side of an equilateral triangle, than the height is $h= a\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, so the area is 
$$
A=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}a^2
$$

now  you have: $a= \frac{2s}{3}$.  Can you do from this?

Anyway:

$$\frac{\sqrt{3}\cdot 4s^2}{36}=\frac{\sqrt{3}\cdot s^2}{9}=\frac{3\cdot s^2}{9\sqrt{3}}=....$$

Comment: yes i can finish from here, thank you

Answer (score 2):

$$
\frac{s^2\sqrt 3} 9 = \frac{s^2\sqrt 3} 9 \cdot \frac{\sqrt 3}{\sqrt 3} = \frac{s^2\cdot 3}{9\sqrt 3} = \frac{s^2}{3\sqrt 3} = \frac{s^2}{\sqrt 3\sqrt 3 \sqrt 3} = \frac{s^2}{\sqrt{3\cdot3\cdot3}}.
$$